# How to add image folder to bootstrap WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I'm working on creating my Boostrap Wordpress theme. But the images are all broken. I guess the fault is from me.

my images are in images folder. While the images folder is in the same .directory as my index file.

is a typical link to my image[my working folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZJra.png)

Please how can I fix the broken image link?

Comment: Bootstrap css files point to `img` folder instead of `images`. Did you alter that in the css files?

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I used images. That made me to notice another difference that wordpress also points to images in upload folder. Though the images showed when I removed the "images" folder and put on the root of my Wordpress installation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what has gone wrong, but you can try to find out whether the broken images are being loaded from the correct URL.

- Right click a broken image and copy its path, check where it leads by visiting the address in your browser.
- If the page gives a 'Not found' notice, there's probably something wrong with the way you formulate the URLs in your theme. Check the image path for any errors.

Comment: I checked the as you said, I did not properly linked the image folder. Thanks Cas